# fill checkboxlist in foreach loop doesnt fill data correctly

Tags: asp.net

I have the following code:

```
string test = "W~3~1,2,3,4,5,6,7";
foreach (var item in test.Substring(4).ToString().Split(','))
{
       CheckBoxListWeeklyDays.SelectedValue = item;
}
```

When I run this code only the last value 7 is checked? How is that possible?

Comment: You have a single `CheckBoxList`, how do you want to set multiple `SelectedValue`? That makes no sense. Maybe you want to [add one item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.items(v=vs.110).aspx) in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:-

```
string test =  "W~3~1,2,3,4,5,6,7";
foreach (var item in test.Substring(4).ToString().Split(','))
{
    ListItem chkItem = CheckBoxListWeeklyDays.Items.FindByValue(item);
    if (chkItem != null)
     chkItem.Selected = true;                     
 }
```

if your problem solved must mark answer and vote.